# How to replace a component via an instance of PicoContainer?

Tags: java, picocontainer

I am working in an environment where I do not control the startup of the PicoContainer, it is provided to me like this:

```
ApplicationManager.getApplication().getPicoContainer().getComponentInstanceOfType(Xyz.class);
```

My question is how I can replace a component via the `PicoContainer`?

Can I get a reference to the `DefaultPicoContainer` or a `MutablePicoContainer` somehow ?

Or can I just cast `PicoContainer` to `MutablePicoContainer` ?

Note: using "old" version, picocontainer 1.3

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it was as simple as to cast to `MutablePicoContainer` :

```
MutablePicoContainer picoContainer = (MutablePicoContainer) ApplicationManager.getApplication().getPicoContainer();
picoContainer.unregisterComponent("a.b.c");
picoContainer.registerComponentImplementation("a.b.c", MyComponent.class);
```

I guess the default `PicoContainer` was provided as a kind of "read-only" container.